# Using "extern C" from C++ with vector for ctypes

Tags: c++, stl, ctypes, extern

My goal is to use ctypes to call from within Python a C++ library I'm creating separately, where I am passing numpy vectors to the C++ routines via pointers. So Python would allocate the memory and just pass the address, and then the C++ routine would access the data and perform its calculations and return the results.

Since I'm new to ctypes, right now I'm gradually building a working toy example. I'm starting off writing the C++ code and creating a C extern interface that the Python wrapper code will use. I haven't even started on the Python wrapper code yet but have some experience with that aspect already.

Here is my example which includes a constructor and a simple total function.

```
// foo.cpp //
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class Data {
public:
  Data(vector<double>*);
  void PrintTotal(void);
private:
  vector<double>* myContents;
};
Data::Data(vector<double>* input) {
  std::cout << "Entered constructor in C++" << std::endl;
  myContents = input;
}
void Data::PrintTotal(void) {
  double total = 0;
  for (int i=0; i<myContents->size(); i++){
    total += (*myContents)[i];
  }
  std::cout << "Hello, my total is " << total << std::endl;
}

extern "C" {
  Data* Data_new(double (**input)) {return new Data(input);}
  void Print_Total(Data* pData) {pData->PrintTotal();}
}
```

Note in particular that I'm using the vector class from the STL, which may be part of the problem described below. The idea is that the class `Data` holds a pointer to the data and does not replicate the data.

When I try to compile this using the command

```
g++ -c -fPIC foo.cpp -o foo.o
```

on our Linux machine, I get the following error:

```
foo.cpp: In function âData* Data_new(double**)â:
foo.cpp:26: error: no matching function for call to âData::Data(double**&)â
foo.cpp:13: note: candidates are: Data::Data(std::vector<double, std::allocator<double> >*)
foo.cpp:6: note:                 Data::Data(const Data&)
```

This seems pretty clear to me: it's saying that the way I call the Data constructor in the third to last line (#26) in `foo.cpp` does not coincide with the constructor I wrote in the C++ part of the code. In both the C++ code and the C extern code, I'm trying to say that the input is a pointer to a vector/array of doubles. I've tried other options on line #36 but it still doesn't compile.

How do I write the extern C part while still using the `vector` class (which I will find useful when I code the real algorithm) in the C++ part? Am I running into trouble because `vector` is part of the STL, which doesn't work well with extern C?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you want the `Date_new` and `Print_total` functions to be usable from a C program, then that won't work. Even when using `extern "C"` the C program will not be able to use classes like `Data`.

Answer (score 0):

First, let's answer your question.  You should change your constructor so that it takes the same arguments as Data_new, and converts the input into a std::vector.  However, it looks like there are a couple of conceptual issues that you need to focus on first:

- Arrays and vectors are not equivalent: if your input points to an
  array, but you want to work with a vector, you'll need to copy
  all of the elements from the array into the vector (or ask a
  vector constructor to do it for you).  You need to do the copy
  because all STL containers hold onto copies of the elements that are
  put in them.
- You can construct the vector using two iterators, with:

  `myContents(data, data + numberOfElements);`

  But this brings up the second conceptual point --- there is nothing in the signature of your code that tells you how large the input array is.
- In Data you're holding onto a pointer to a vector, but you
  never free it.  This is a memory leak.  That being said, you should
  probably just hold onto a vector, not a pointer to a vector.